# How do I make a text box show text one letter at a time in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox

not sure if I'm working this correctly but I was wondering if there was a way to have a sentence fill a  text box one letter or one word at a time when you run the application. (Using Visual Studio in C#)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Assuming Windows Forms, the obvious option to do something over time is to use a `Timer` and make the appropriate change on each `Tick`.

Comment: Please take moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then consider revising your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it saving the full sentence in a variable and then update the `TextBox` with a `Timer` http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx . Every `Tick` the `Timer` will either update an index to the current letter to add, or just compare the TextBox.Text to the sentence and get the n+1th character.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Timer`.

```
static int Main()
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
   //timer tick inteval in ms
   myTimer.Interval = 5000;
   myTimer.Start();
}

static void TimerTick(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
   //do Logic here
}
```